# CSS footer not sticking at bottom after using V-for to render list of items in Vuejs

Tags: css, vue.js, bootstrap-4

Footer is ignoring the items I am rendering using v-for and is showing under those items rather than at the end. It is working fine on other pages as it's stuck at the bottom.

```
<template>
  <div>
        <!-- Item rendering -->
        <div class="main-div2">
          <div
            class="div3"
            v-for="(product, index) in $store.getters.getProducts"
            :key="index"
          >
            <img class="img-style" :src="product.image" />
            <p>{{ product.discription }}</p>
            <h4>Price: {{ product.price }}</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
    <TheFooter />
  </div>
</template>
```

Here are the CSS classes for that component

```
.main-div2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 20vh;
  justify-content: center;
  z-index: 1;
  /* grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit,minmax(50px,1fr));
  grid-template-areas:
    "div2 div3 div4 div5 div6"; */
}
.div3 {
  flex: 1 1 250px;
  position: relative;
  height: 350px;
}
```

And this is the footer main div class

```
.wrapper {
  height: 350px;
  background: rgb(219, 210, 210);
  margin-top: 7rem;
  width: 100%;
  bottom:0;
  position:absolute;
}
```

Comment: your footer is positioned `absolute`. That means it does not take any place on the page, it is just placed on the end of the parent that has position `relative`.

Comment: @Serg yes you are right. On top of that, I specified the height on the main div that contains the render list using v-for. So, it was not taking the original height of content rather it was taking that specified height, which made the footer follow that height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution, by removing the height specified on parent div that contained the rendered list.

```
.main-div2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  z-index: 1;

}
```

Also removed the position absolute to make it follow the natural margin order.

```
.wrapper {
  height: 350px;
  background: rgb(219, 210, 210);
  margin-top: 7rem;
  width: 100%;

}
```